# TeamSpeak 3 doesn't see virtual sink monitor as capture device

Tags: pulseaudio, teamspeak

So I am trying to create a music bot for TeamSpeak 3 and after some research I found that I have to create a so called virtual sink (which is basically a virtual output device) with pulsaudio and then feed the music into that sink. Every virtual sink you create comes with a monitor which acts as a virtual input device that records the output sink. Now the only thing left to do should be selecting the virtual sink monitor as capture device in TeamSpeak 3, problem is: the TeamSpeak 3 doesn't see the monitor, even though it is clearly listed as input device in the system settings.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question because I'm convinced that PulseAudio and Teamspeak behave identically on Debian and Ubuntu as far as relevant for this question and, as such, Ubuntu users would equally benefit from it. Additionally OP self-answered the question with a viable solution. I remove all, in my opinion irrelevant, references to Debian.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution to this problem: in pavucontrol there is a recording tab where you can set the input device for TS3 (or any application that records something) to anything you want, in my case the sink monitor.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. A series of screenshots would be very helpful. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.) Send me a note if you want my up-vote after the improvement. :-)